# Pokemon Evolution across types

Tags: pokemon

Are you allowed to evolve a pokemon to a different type?  For example, I have a leaf Burmy.  I have a leaf Wormadam and a metal Wordamam.  Can I evolve my leaf Burmy to a metal Wordamam?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can evolve.   Pokemon evolution doesn't depend on the type of either the basic or evolved pokemon.   What matters is that the name of the Pokemon listed as "evolves from" on the Stage 1 match exactly the name of the Basic Pokemon.    So, for example, your leaf/metal Wormadam state on the card "Evolves from Burmy".   Either can evolve from "Burmy", but neither could evolve from "Team Magma's Burmy" .

Comment: Thanks Glen.  That was my assumption I just didn't want it to only be an ASSUMPTION.  It is always hard to find examples of this in the rules and some of them are ambiguous.  If you have any links to official sites, please do include them in your answer although i have already accepted it.